# node.js: Path not being created using fs lib

Tags: javascript, node.js

No directory is created using fs.mkdirSync function - what's wrong here!?

```
var fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path');
fs.mkdirSync(path.join("c:","b"))
console.log(fs.existsSync(path.join("c:","b")))
```

Output is:

```
/temp/file.js:3
fs.mkdirSync(path.join("c:","b"))
   ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'c:/b'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/temp/file.js:3:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:418:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:533:3
```

Then i created a directory x in c:\ and executed the following

```
var fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path');
console.log(fs.existsSync(path.join("c:","x")))
```

but again got:

```
false
```

Comment: Could you provide the result of `path.sep`? It is strange that `join` returns path with forward slash on Windows. Is it Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that your host OS is Windows, but Node.js thinks it's running on some posix-compliant OS, probably due to being invoked through Docker, Cygwin environment or the new Windows Linux environment.

For Cygwin and Windows Linux environments, the `C:\` drive is accessible as `/c` folder:

```
path.join('/c', 'b')
```

If that does not work, you may try to force Node.js to treat the path as `win32` paths by executing

```
path.win32.join('C:', 'b')
```